# How to configure a Slack API OAuth Token which has read-only access to public channels only?

Tags: slack, slack-api

(Slack API n00b here)

I'm trying to use the Slack API for searching through messages in some of our public slack channels (internal to our organization).

I'm using the `https://www.slack.com/api/search.messages` API via the [Python SDK](https://slack.dev/python-slack-sdk/web/index.html), which means I'm doing the following:

```py
import logging
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from pprint import pprint
    
    
def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    # TOKEN:
    t = 'xoxp-***'

    print("Getting client")
    c = WebClient(token=t)
    response = c.search_messages(query='in:#some_public_channel some-search-string')
    print("Response Code: {}".format(response.status_code))
    print("Found {} messages.".format(len(response.data['messages']['matches'])))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can only get the code above working if I use a "**User OAuth Token**", which unfortunately is a token that also has access to all private messages related to that user.

I would like to have an OAuth token that can only search through public channels (read-only). In that way, it could be shared among members of the same team (for example).

Any suggestions how I could solve this?

### Background information:

1. If I try to use a "Bot User Auth Token" I get **not_allowed_token_type** error.

```
DEBUG:slack_sdk.web.slack_response: Received the following response - 
status: 200, 
headers: {...}, 
body: {'ok': False, 'error': 'not_allowed_token_type'}
```

2. The tokens I'm using are generated via an "app" which I created only for this purpose:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the [search.messages](https://api.slack.com/methods/search.messages) API is only available to users, not bots. The best workaround I could suggest is this -

- Grant your bot the [channels:history](https://api.slack.com/scopes/channels:history) and [channels:join](https://api.slack.com/scopes/channels:join) scopes
- Call [conversations.join](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.join) for the relevant public channels.
- Call [conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) and iterate over the results looking for `some-search-string`